# drawing sprite in pygame from a class constructor

Tags: constructor, pygame, sprite, pycharm, blit

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

class PlayerNinja(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

x = 0
y = 0
width = 112
height = 102


def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    super(PlayerNinja, self).__init__()

    self.image = pygame.image.load("player.png")

.
.
.


###########################################################################

def main():

    from PlayerNinja import *

    print "Testing"

    player = PlayerNinja(10, 10)
    a = player.getX()
    print "X: " + str(a)

    player.setX(50)
    b = player.getX()
    print "new X: " + str(b)

    player.setY(50)
    c = player.getY()
    print "Y: " + str(c)

    screenWidth = 800
    screenHeight = 700

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth, screenHeight))

    white = (255,255,255)
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

        screen.fill(white)

        screen.blit(player, (b, c))

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

When I run main, I get the error

```
screen.blit(player, b, c)
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not PlayerNinja"
```

I have tried replacing parts of the line with `pygame.Surface`. When I used the same format (`screen.blit(player, (x,y))`) with a different character it worked... I think it is because in this case I load the image in the constructor of the class, whereas the other time I wasn't using a class. I had to look up the `super().__init__()`-part, so maybe that's part of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to code

```
screen.blit(player.image, (b, c))
```

because the [`.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) method need a **[`pyagme.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html)-object** (a loaded image is also a surface in PyGame) **as first argument**. You need to pass a surface instance to `.blit()`, which is stored in your `PlayerNinja` sprite object ("`player`") as the attribute `self.image`.

The other parts (`super().__init__()`) are fine in my opinion. :)